# How to get the Authentication context inside WebFilter in Spring webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

How can I get access to the security context / authenticton object in a `WebFilter` in webflux environment?

Problem here is that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is always null, even for authenticated users.

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public WebFilter loggingFilter() {
    return new WebFilter() {
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            //apply some custom logic based on the authentication
            
            //then continue
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
    };
}
```

I tried that I can access the context successfully in a `@GetMapping` method as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/ok")
public Mono<String> ok() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .flatMap(s -> {
                System.out.println(s.getAuthentication());
                return Mono.just("OK");
            });
}
```

But how can I integrate this to the WebFilter?

Comment: i think several things are at work here. First has your request even passed through the security filter and actually authenticated someone so that something is placed in the security context? also, have you instead tried implementing the filter and registering as a component? please list all you have tried because atm. Also, please debug, please produce a runnable example

Comment: No, the main problem is that I cannot use the sync `SecurityContextHolder`, but somehow  have to integrate the async `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` into the `WebFilter`, but I don't know how...

Comment: `return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.get.....flatMap( .... ).then(chainFilter(.....)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the hint from @Toerktumlare, I could resolve my issue as follows:

```
return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .doOnNext((sc) -> {
            if (sc.getAuthentication() != null)
                //custom logic on sc.getAuthentication().getName()
        })
        .then(chain.filter(exchange));
```